# adjust photo size auto small large

Tags: resize, photo

I have a website for pictures and I am not satisfied with the quality that displays because users add big photos and script resizes them and lose quality. This website uses GD library or ImageMagick , I want the picture to be displayed in an auto option but to add two buttons for users to view photos enlarged or reduced size.
This is the demo website of the script that I use: http://artvenue-abhi003.rhcloud.com/image/26/odit-nisi